# connect to firebase using API key and application username password

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication

I worked with firebase connectivity from application and from backend server using admin SDK.

Firebase admin SDK used Service account key to connect to firebase backend.
Here my use case is: i have a python package which will get used by client, here i do not want to use Service account key and admin SDK. I wanted to use API key and if user enters valid username and password of application (assuming user is already signed up) ,  user will get access to firebase backend. (Obviously as per security rules)

I am not able to find a method to access firebase backend using API key and applications username/Password from python script. If anyone knows it please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Admin SDK that Firebase provides for Python is only meant to be used in trusted environments, and doesn't allow signing in with username/password. All code using the Admin SDK is accessing Firebase using administrative privileges, so it is not suitable for your use-case. Firebase itself doesn't provide a SDK for client-side access using Python. So the only option remaining that Firebase provides is to call the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth) from your code.

There is a third party library called [Pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase) that allows you to [sign in users](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#authentication) (by wrapping the REST API mentioned above):

```
# Get a reference to the auth service
auth = firebase.auth()

# Log the user in
user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
```

Comment: Thanks for help, REST API way worked for me. Using rest api i obtained ApiKey (jwtToken) and refresh token. Then authorized next requests using it.  This library is also good option but later on i wanted to login using facebook/gmail/github etc which is not supported in this lib. Bunch of thanks again to you.

Answer (score 1):

IF you want to control the backend access with an API key - you can't.

> Unlike how API keys are typically used, API keys for Firebase services are not used to control access to backend resources; that can only be done with Firebase Security Rules (to control which users can access resources) and App Check (to control which apps can access resources).

as per [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys)

Comment: yes, to control backend access i will use security rule.  But here i wanted to do what typical firebase application does. We provide API key to application then user sign in from and then that user has access to firestore (say to create post). 

My requirement is , i want to do similar thing from python code and not from application code (web/android/ios)

Comment: Oh ok I think i understand you. I thought you wanted something else.

Comment: Using firebase authentication in python app to get the user.

Comment: @HarisWilson, 
Yes exactly, Do you know how to accomplish it  ?